# Number of strings

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a (DNA) string of length **`l`**. e.g. `ACG`.

For each position in the string, there are 3 alternative values that the position can be changes to: `A -> CTG, C-> ATG, T -> AGC, G -> ATC`.

I am allowed to change **`d`** positions in the original string to any of the possible values for that particular position. This is called d-neighbourhood of a string.

For instance, if `d=1`, I am allowed to change `1` value in the string `ACG` at any position. 
So the possible strings are:

```
CCG
TCG
GCG
AAG
ATG
AGG
ACA
ACC
ACT
ACG
```

Here the number of strings generated is 9 + the original string (`ACG`).

I need to come up with the **formula to calculate the number of strings generated** for arbitrary **`l`** and arbitrary **`d`** `(d <= l)`.

So far, I have come up with:

$$ \text{number  of  strings} = C_{l}^d * 3^d$$

but I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Not sure I am following.  surely $ACG$ has length $3$, not length $1$?  Also...is the answer for "$ACG$ with $d=1$" $9$ or is it $10$?  That is to say,do I have to use all my $d$ changes or can I change any number of positions $\{0,1,\cdots, d-1,d\}$?

Comment: @lulu: I think that's a $l$ as in *l*ength, not a $1$ as in $1, 2, 3$.

Comment: @BrianTung  Oh! you are probably right.  If I stare at it, it does look different from the "$1$" further down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your  considerations are sound. Let me repeat the situation in slightly different words. We assume an Alphabet $V=\{A,C,G,T\}$, consider words of length $l$ and have a set of *production rules* to obtain a word from another one. These rules are
\begin{align*}
&A\longrightarrow C|T|G\\
&C\longrightarrow A|T|G\\
&T\longrightarrow A|G|C\\
&G\longrightarrow A|C|T\\
\end{align*}

The symbol `$|$' means *or* and provides alternatives. We observe a word $w$ is transformed into a word $w^\prime$ by applying to one or more characters of $w$ a corresponding production rule.

> We conclude:
>
> - Since each of  the characters  in $V$ has three production rules, changing $d$ characters in a word $w$ produces $3^d$ different words.
> - In a word $w$ of length $l$ there are $\binom{l}{d}$ ways to select $d$ characters. So, we get a total of
>     \begin{align*}
>   3^d\binom{l}{d}
>   \end{align*}
>     different words having *distance* $d$ from $w$, since precisely $d$  characters have been changed.

**Note:** Usually,  when we are talking about a *neighbourhood* of a word $w$ of distance $d$, we mean all words which have distance $\leq d$ to the word. In this case we can say, there are
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^d\binom{l}{j}3^j
\end{align*}
different words in the $d$-neighbourhood of $w$, including the word $w$ itself, having distance $0$ from it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the note! I had this question, too, and you answered it without even asking.

Comment: @Oleksandra: You're welcome! :-)